# What is causing my application crashes? Borderlands 2, Adium, more

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, crash, adium, steam

Borderlands 2 (purchased, downloaded, run via Steam) crashes on launch for me. This is the first time I've ever really had application crashes, other than the typical "Application has quit unexpectedly" line. I do get a crashlog, which I've put into pastebin here:

http://pastebin.com/bKgKLJv0

I have no idea where to start. help?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Borderlands 2, there is a [thread on the Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/666827315381356903/?l=english) with a similar crash log, and the solution appears to be **updating to Mavericks**, with a few people confirming it worked for them.